# Set UITableViewCell height to UIImage height?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a custom TableViewCell, and i want its height to match the size of the UIImage. The UIImageView in the Cell is set to aspect fit, and i want the UIImageview to be as high as the UIImage it contains, and the width to be equal to the width of the table view (screen width). In the method heightForRowAtIndexPath: I have the image that the cell at a given indexPath.row contains. The cells are configured that way, that if i set the heightForRowAtIndexPath to let's say 500, the imageview is the only view that will get stretched.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let image = comics[indexPath.row].image

        return image.size.height + 103
}
```

the 103 are the points that make the rest of the cell height (buttons and a label)(see sceenshot).

Now the problem: all cells are too hight! and as if this wouldnt be strange enough, some of them are too short??? (picture)  And i have read a lot similar posts but none of them answers my question.
Somehow the image.size.height is larger than the actual image in the imageview??
I just want the uiimageview to be the same size as the image in it, in mode AspectFit.

Do you have any ideas on this? If you have any further questions pleas ask me!
Thank you!
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLhuI.png)

Comment: all cells have image? are you sure about the relation of the image array and the indexPath.row ?

Comment: maybe you need to calculate image height with ratio image.width/screen.width ?

Comment: Yeah this array is the data source array, i use it to return the rows in section as well.

Comment: But why would the ratio matter? the imageview is (with constraints) fixed to the edge of the screen

Comment: The problem may be with the resolution of the images, print the size of each cell to "debug" it, you will probably have to work with the aspect ratio and no only with the height.

Comment: Ok ill try that, thank you!

Comment: Why not use the height of the image view?

Comment: I want to make the imageview the size of the uiimage

Comment: Huh? The image size is probably different from the image view size. Try using the image view size to calculate it instead of the image size.

Comment: But i have to know how big the image is to set the size of the imageview; i dont want the imageview to have blue space (See screenshot )

Comment: Thank you! the aspect ratio was the solution, i added it as a solution to my question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you so much guys!  The thing with the aspect ratio did it:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let image = comics[indexPath.row].image
        let aspectRatioImg = image.size.height / image.size.width

        return view.bounds.width * aspectRatioImg + 103
    }
```